# A `button` that is `display: flex` doesn't take full width of container

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/atomanyih/pen/Jjbajba)

My understanding is adding `display: flex` (not `inline-flex`) to an element should make it a flex container in block layout [(spec)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers), and thus take the full width of the container. [(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Unlike other elements, a `button` does not take the full width of its container.

Why is this happening?

*Note: To be clear, I have a workaround for my particular use case. I'm looking to understand why this doesn't seem to match the layout model*

---

*edit*: example code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button flex-container">Button</button>
  <a href="#" class="link flex-container">Link</a>
  <div class="flex-container">a div</div>
    <span class="flex-container">a span</span>
</div>
```

```
.button {
  border: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  
  padding:  8px 0;
  
  & > * + * {
      margin-top: 8px;
  }
}
```

Comment: button are special element (will try to find the relevant question ..)

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869#c2

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the content of the button in a span, and make the span the flex container.